# Problem with an Website Platform configuration

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, vs-web-site-project

- I just tried to change the hosting provider, the previous one worked
  on **5.3 php** version, and the platform worked.
- After i moved the **domain/files/Db** it gives me those errors.
- Yes, i've already changed php version in 5.3. Attachment with the
  errors.

  The website url is http://preluari-creante.ro.

Here is the error log image [Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsizm.jpg)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

it is a bad way you choosed, a better way is using **akeeba backup** to backup your joomla and when new host avalible using **kickstart** (a plugin of the akeeba backup) to restore all of your joomla files, ex: backend, frontend, mysql, extentions, users and etc in one big file.
https://www.akeebabackup.com/

its recommended to use same version of php in the new host. but you can change it when using kickstart to restore.
other ways is not recommended.